# Spark union column order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've come across something strange recently in Spark. As far as I understand, given the column based storage method of spark dfs, the order of the columns really don't have any meaning, they're like keys in a dictionary.

During a `df.union(df2)`, does the order of the columns matter? I would've assumed that it shouldn't, but according to the wisdom of sql forums it does.

So we have `df1`

```
df1
|  a|   b|
+---+----+
|  1| asd|
|  2|asda|
|  3| f1f|
+---+----+

df2
|   b|  a|
+----+---+
| asd|  1|
|asda|  2|
| f1f|  3|
+----+---+

result
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
|   1| asd|
|   2|asda|
|   3| f1f|
| asd|   1|
|asda|   2|
| f1f|   3|
+----+----+
```

It looks like the schema from df1 was used, but the data appears to have joined following the order of their original dataframes. 
Obviously the solution would be to do `df1.union(df2.select(df1.columns))`

But the main question is, why does it do this? Is it simply because it's part of pyspark.sql, or is there some underlying data architecture in Spark that I've goofed up in understanding?

code to create test set if anyone wants to try

```
d1={'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['asd','asda','f1f']}
d2={ 'b':['asd','asda','f1f'], 'a':[1,2,3],}
pdf1=pd.DataFrame(d1)
pdf2=pd.DataFrame(d2)
df1=spark.createDataFrame(pdf1)
df2=spark.createDataFrame(pdf2)
test=df1.union(df2)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in spark Union is not done on metadata of columns and data is not shuffled like you would think it would.  rather union is done on the column numbers  as in, if you are unioning 2 Df's both must have the same numbers of columns..you will have to take in consideration of positions of your columns previous to doing union. unlike SQL or Oracle or other RDBMS, underlying files in spark are physical files.  hope that answers your question

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Is this the only operation where the column order is used? Or are there other situations? I just assumed that unions work like joins and data gets shuffled around, guess it explains why unions are relatively quick

Comment: I haven't had to deal with too much column ordering tbh. but unions are one case that i can think of.

Answer (score 50):

The Spark union is implemented according to standard SQL and therefore resolves the columns by position. This is also stated by the API [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union):

> Return a new DataFrame containing union of rows in this and another frame.
>
> This is equivalent to UNION ALL in SQL. To do a SQL-style set union (that does >deduplication of elements), use this function followed by a distinct.
>
> Also as standard in SQL, this function resolves columns by position (not by name).

Since **Spark >= 2.3** you can use [unionByName](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName) to union two dataframes were the column names get resolved.

Comment: Is there any performance impact of using `unionByName` vs `union`?

Comment: Of course because spark needs to check the existing columnnames before but it is a small one ([link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blame/cee4ecbb16917fa85f02c635925e2687400aa56b/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L1894)).

Comment: Also, unionByName is apparently like unionAll in that it doesn't dedupe records.

Comment: @combinatorist That is correct. You have to use it followed by [.distinct()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.distinct) to deduplicate rows.